# AJAX not working with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to load in  `<div class="test">`   some content from another URL ex: `http://someurl.com/default.aspx`.

I tried this code:

```
$(".test").load( 'http://someurl.com/default.aspx');
```

But it doesn't work.

With local file it works, but not with http://...

Can somebody help me?

Thanks

Comment: Is it loading the URL in the net tab in Firebug? Any errors? What's the status? 404?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like you have bumped into the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). You have to use a relative path for the `load()` method, otherwise most browsers will simply return an empty `responseText`.

As one possible workaround, you could set up a very simple [reverse proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy) (using [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html) if you are on Apache). This would allow you to use relative paths in your AJAX request, while the HTTP server would be acting as a proxy to any "remote" location.

The fundamental configuration directive to set up a reverse proxy in [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html) is the ProxyPass. You would typically use it as follows:

```
ProxyPass     /ajax/     http://someurl.com/
```

In this case, the browser would be requesting `/ajax/default.aspx` but in fact the server would serve this by acting as a proxy to `http://someurl.com/default.aspx`.

If you are using IIS, you may want to use the [Managed Fusion URL Rewriter and Reverse Proxy](http://www.codeplex.com/Wikipage?ProjectName=urlrewriter) to set up a reverse proxy.

Answer (score 0):

you can not do cross-domain with AJAX. this is a small solution in PHP [load funcion](http://www.bin-co.com/php/scripts/load/):

JS:

```
$(".test").load("myloadurl.php", {url: 'http://someurl.com/default.aspx'} );
```

myloadurl.php

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/html');
print load($_GET['url']);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over someurl.org you should use JSONP which is a proper way to do cross-browser AJAX requests.

For example you have http://someurl.org/default.php containing something like this:

```
<?php
echo $_GET['jsoncallback'] . '(' . $results_in_json_format . ')';
```

Now you can make your AJAX query with jQuery like this:

```
$.getJSON("http://someurl.com/default.php?jsoncallback=?", function(data) {
     $(".test").html(data);
});
```